# Need to match data in different sheets and replace data in another cell if it's a match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas, array-formulas, vba

I need to match data in column A2 and so on in sheet 1 to data in column A2 and so on in sheet 2. If the data in column A of sheet 1 and sheet 2 match I need the data in column B & C of sheet 2 to replace data in column B & C of sheet 1. I know VERY little about doing this kind of stuff so any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

SHEET 1

```
     A     B     C
2  12345  5.35  9.95
3  15874  4.22  10.99
4  11111  2.24  5.99
5  98745  5.33  9.95
6  88552  4.24  8.95
```

SHEET 2

```
     A     B     C
2  11111  2.09  5.79
3  12345  5.11  9.89
4  88552  4.01  8.79
```

NEED SHEET 1 to change to

```
     A     B     C
2  12345  5.11  9.89
3  15874  4.22  10.99
4  11111  2.09  5.79
5  98745  5.33  9.95
6  88552  4.01  8.79
```

Answer (score 1):

On a third sheet use these functions

```
column a ='sheet1'!a2
column b =if('sheet1'!b2='sheet2'!b2,'sheet2'!b2,'sheet1'!b2)
column c =if('sheet1'!c2='sheet2'!c2,'sheet2'!c2,'sheet1'!c2)
```

Copy sheet3 and paste the values into sheet1.
This should work unless column a does match. or if you need to do this dynamically. If column a doesn't match some vlookups can be thrown in.

I your data does match in column a your formulas could look something like this.

```
column a ='sheet1'!a2
column b =if(not(iserror(vlookup(a2,'sheet2'!a:c,2,false))),vlookup(a2,'sheet2'!a:c,2,false),vlookup(a2,'sheet1'!a:c,2,false))
column c =if(not(iserror(vlookup(a2,'sheet2'!a:c,3,false))),vlookup(a2,'sheet2'!a:c,3,false),vlookup(a2,'sheet1'!a:c,3,false))
```

Comment: I don't know how to do vlookups :-/

Comment: Sheet 1 has a lot more data in it then sheet 2. I only need the ones from sheet two to change on sheet 1 and have no clue how to go about it

Answer (score 0):

this is too much to put in a comment so I'm putting it in answer.

The way I under stand is, since sheet1 has more data, you only want to be doing this comparison when sheet1 and 2 both have data on the row. so If sheet1 has data in rows 1 - 100, and sheet2 has data in rows 1 to 50, you only want to be doing this comparison for the first 50 rows in sheet1 right?

So, rather than copying and pasting formulas, what you can do is, in sheet1, find an unused column. go to the first row. in the formula box, type: "=if(" without the quotes. now, select the first cell to compare, according to your example you'd select sheet1, A2. then type "=" without quotes. then select the second cell you want to compare - in your example, sheet2, A2. then type "," without quotes. then select the cell from which you want the data if the first 2 cells are equal. in your example, sheet2 B2. then type "," without quotes, then select the cell with the data to use if the first 2 cells are not equal. in your example, sheet1 b2. then type ")" without the quotes.

so using your example, the function would look similar to how bigtree had it: `=if('sheet1'!A2='sheet2'!A2,'sheet2'!b2,'sheet1'!b2)`

so, this will compare sheet1 cell A2 with sheet2 A2 and if they are equal, the cell you put the formula in will the have the value of sheet2 b2, and if they are not equal, the cell with this formula will have the value of sheet1 B2. then, drag this formula down for however many rows you want, and the formula will adjust automatically for each row. you'll see the numbers increase. then, select the column with the formulas, right click and select copy, then right click and go to paste special, and click values. this will make it so the column contains only the values, not the formulas, now you can paste this data in column B sheet 1.

you can reuse this formula for whatever columns, just follow the steps.

HTH, good luck!

Comment: I need sheet 1 to find the matching SKU numbers (column A) in sheet 2 (column A) and replace column b and c on sheet one to the coresponding row and columns B & C on sheet two. There are about 3500 price changes on sheet two that need to be updated on sheet one so I can upload the changes. Sheet two SKU's are mixed in everywhere in sheet one. THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP @user2777399

Comment: stack isnt free consulting. its pointers, and sometimes small formulas. What you want is alot more involved than the simple formulas bigtree and I posted. nobody is going to take an hour of their own time and code your stuff. thats what consultants are for. having said that, you can probably just do a sort on the columns, and it'll sort the columns in alphabetical order, at which point our formulas will work.